# Why is there redundancy in xsi:schemaLocation declaration?

Tags: java, xml, spring

The xml schema location contains `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` which is already the schema global namespace. Then why is it always repeated in the `xsi:schemaLocation` element? The XSD/DTD defines the XML and so is needed for XML validation by the parser but why the repeated namespace?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <bean id="test" />
</beans>
```

Comment: If you had multiple namespace schemas defined, you'd need to be able to tell the validator where each namespace's schema is.  That's done by pairing the namespace with its location in the schemaLocation.

Comment: @IanMcLaird You should make this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only looks redundant because you only have one namespace schema defined.  In cases where there are multiple schemas, you need to pair up the namespace with its schema definition.

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.example.com/foo"
     xmlns:bar="http://www.example.com/bar"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/foo http://www.example.com/foo.xsd
                         http://www.example.com/bar http://www.example.com/bar.xsd">
  <bar:tag />
</foo>
```

This means that the default namespace is `http://www.example.com/foo` with its schema located at `http://www.example.com/foo.xsd`, but we're also using the namespace `http://www.example.com/bar` whose schema is located at `http://www.example.com/bar.xsd`  The `schemaLocation` attribute is a whitespace delimited list of namespace/schema pairs.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

states that the default namespace, ie. if none is specified, is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans`.

This

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

states that the namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` can be validated with the XSD found here: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd.